# How to save an array of JSON objects (with nested objects) to state in React

Tags: json, reactjs, state

I'm trying to save an array of JSON objects returned from an API call to state in React (so that I can use the data to render a table). I'm getting the error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {street, suite, city, zipcode, geo}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I can't figure out how to fix this. It looks like the JSON is being stored inside an array as it should be. However, there are also nested objects inside the objects that may be causing an issue, for example:

```
address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Here's my code below:

```
let tableData = []
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => { 
                tableData = data
                props.addItem(tableData)
            })
```

Here's the addItem function:

```
addItem(item) {
     this.setState(function(prevState) {
        return {
          tables: [...prevState.tables, item]
        }
      })
}
```

### UPDATE

Here's how I am rendering the data:

App.js:

```
render() {
     return (
          <div>
               {this.state.tables.map(item => {
                 return (<TableComponent key={item} data={item} />)
               })}
          </div>
     )
}
```

TableComponent.js:

```
class TableComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.getHeader = this.getHeader.bind(this);
      this.getRowsData = this.getRowsData.bind(this);
      this.getKeys = this.getKeys.bind(this);
    }
    
    getKeys = function(){
      return Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
    }
    
    getHeader = function(){
      let keys = this.getKeys();
      return keys.map((key, index)=>{
        return <th key={key}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
      })
    }
    
    getRowsData = function(){
      let items = this.props.data;
      let keys = this.getKeys();
      return items.map((row, index)=>{
        return <tr key={index}><RenderRow key={index} data={row} keys={keys}/></tr>
      })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>{this.getHeader()}</tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.getRowsData()}
            </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          
        );
    }
}

const RenderRow = (props) =>{
  return props.keys.map((key, index)=>{
    return <td key={props.data[key]}>{props.data[key]}</td>
  })
}
```

Comment: Please post where you are rendering the data.  This error occurs when you try to render a JavaScript object directly to the DOM.

Comment: Updated to add info about where I'm rendering the data. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment @ChrisB. I couldn't tell from the error message that the problem was in the rendering of the data and not in saving it to state (because of the line numbers being referenced in the error). I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message threw me off here because it made it seem like the issue was in saving the objects to state. However, as was pointed out in the comments, the error happened during rendering. To solve the issue I changed RenderRow to the following:

```
const RenderRow = (props) =>{
  return props.keys.map((key, index)=>{
    return <td key={props.data[key]}>{typeof props.data[key] === "object" ? JSON.stringify(props.data[key]) : props.data[key]}</td>
  })
}
```

Specifically, the piece that I changed is to first check whether a specific element is an object, and if it is, to use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to a string before rendering it to the screen.